# Windows have deleted my partition where ubuntu was, now I can't boot to ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2

So I wanted to merge multiple unallocated spaces or it was partitions (not sure anymore) via AOMEI and EaseUS partition tools on windows 7 and it done that, but I couldn't boot to ubuntu (16.04) anymore, it just points me on boot to something like grub command line, when I type 'exit' it boots to windows but I need ubuntu back or few files to be exact if I can't get whole OS.. 
Here is what i tried :
I booted ubuntu 16.04 from CD and installed program called boot-repair, and choosen recommended repair it has finished it process and when I rebooted it was all the same, I can boot windows but not ubuntu.
Is there any way to fix this and get ubuntu back?

One more thing there was a swap partition around 4 GB it seems that 2 partitions were merged and on windows they are shown as unallocated space.

Here is report from boot repair tool:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r9tt4dZSqc/

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. It does not normally fix partition issues, but perhaps testdisk can. Need to see what partitions you have. https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: R-Studio is the last chance, I think.

Comment: I didn't see the link to pastebin report, but it has uploaded it, I'll do it again and look into TestDisk anf see what happens

Comment: @oldfred here is report from boot repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r9tt4dZSqc/ I see it couldn't find ubuntu probably because ubuntu is listed as unallocated space, any toughts?

Comment: You are just showing NTFS partitions and gaps that may have been the Linux partitions. I would try testdisk and see if it sees the partitions. Note that testdisk often finds multiple previous versions of partitions and you have to choose a combination that does not overlap & keeps the existing partitions you want. I think new version of testdisk now uses sectors, so you can compare with report that shows exact sectors that are gaps.

Comment: I tried to use TestDisk but it couldn't help or I'm doing something wrong. However I tired of wrestling with os-es and I'm going from beginning formating whole HDD thanks anyway